# In the SAML tracer window, what does red text color indicate?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, single-sign-on, saml, firefox-addon-webextensions, devtools

1. Install SAML tracer and login to a service using SAML.
   [SAML-tracer on Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/saml-tracer/mpdajninpobndbfcldcmbpnnbhibjmch)
2. In the SAML tracer window, noticed the http GET and POST messages appear in different colors, including the GET messages for SAML. Example: green, gold/yellow gray, red.

What does a red text mean? What do the different colors indicate?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find this documented anywhere either, so I dug into [the extension's source](https://github.com/Uninett/SAML-tracer/blob/ed5c68158311452f6000803469e6926907a73703/src/SAMLTrace.js#L736) and [CSS](https://github.com/Uninett/SAML-tracer/blob/ed5c68158311452f6000803469e6926907a73703/src/resources/css/samltrace.css#L129). Grey is the default colour, and it seems to only be used for requests which have not received a response from the network: either because they're still in transit, or because the request was handled by the browser's cache. All of the other possible colours are based on [the HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) of the response:

- 1xx (informational response; technically implemented as 0-199) is coloured black
- 2xx (success) is green
- 3xx (redirection) is orange
- 4xx (client error) is red
- 5xx (server error) is also red

It would be nice if there was a colour distinction between client- and server-side errors, but you can click on the request and see the actual status code from the response headers.